# How do I reference the number of rows in a group in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to write a function to use with `dplyr` that uses the number of rows in the group.  Is there any way to reference the number of rows in the group in `dplyr`, other than just creating a new column?  This would be equivalent to the `.N` variable in `data.table`.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
library(dplyr)
library(RcppRoll)

# Function I'm trying to create
rollingMean <- function(x, n = 4) 
  if (.N < n) {  # I want to test whether we have more than 4 rows
    out <- mean(x)  # if so, return the overall mean
  } else {
    out <- roll_meanr(x, n)
  }
  return(out)
  }

# Fake data
tmp <- data.frame(X = 1:21, grouping = c(rep(letters[1:2], 10), letters[3]))

tmp %>%
  group_by(grouping) %>%
  mutate(ma = rollingMean(X)) %>%
  tail  # Of course, this doesn't work, but the value for ma for the last row should be 21
```

This seems like it would be fairly simple to do.  Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: are you just looking for `if (length(x) < n)` ?  There is a `?n` function in `dplyr`, but it's special -- " can only be used from within ‘summarise’, ‘mutate’ and ‘filter’"

Comment: @BenBolker yes, that did the trick.  Thanks!  I knew it had to be something simple that I was missing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the test in `rollingMean` just needs to be

```
if (length(x) < n)
```

There is an `?n` function in `dplyr`, but it's special --

> ... can only be used from within ‘summarise’, ‘mutate’ and ‘filter’ ...

Comment: I should probably ask this in a separate question, but do you know if there's a way to do this for the row index, too (i.e., to reference the value of `row_number()`)?